# ATI Radeon HD 7770 no GPU rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

So I don't have an option to turn on GPU rendering in settings. I only have the option for CPU rendering.
Here's my specs:

- ATI Radeon HD 7770 1GB  GDDR5 1GH
- AMD Phenom II 4x 960T 3GHz
- 4Gb DDR3 1600MHz RAM

My GPU driver is version 13.9.
I see people running fine with this GPU, but for some reason I don't have an option to turn it on.

I need to deliver my design tomorrow so I need this fast and CPU just can't render it that fast.

I'm running Blender 2.69 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Can you link to some pages that show this GPU rendering? AFAIK OpenCL doesn't work yet with cycles, see [this wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/OpenCL) for more information on why.

Comment: This question is too localized to specific hardware/configuration: see, http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic There is lots of discussion & info on ATI/cycles compatibility on blenderartists.

Answer (score 6):

OpenCL isn't fully supported yet (which is what AMD/ATI cards use to render):

> Cycles has two GPU rendering modes: through CUDA, which is the
>   preferred method for NVidia graphics cards; and OpenCL, which is
>   intended to support rendering on AMD/ATI graphics cards. The
>   implementation of OpenCL is only in an experimental stage and disabled
>   in official builds. ([source](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/GPU_Rendering))

You could try to find a build on [GraphicAll](http://graphicall.org), but there is no guarantee it'll work.

I would recommend just rendering it on CPU. If you are really pressed for time, there are a few things you can do to speed things up:

- **Set the size of the tiles lower** (Render Tab > Performance). The CPU renders faster if the tiles are smaller (GPU renders faster on bigger tiles).
- **Set the threads to fixed and set them as high as possible** (Render Tab > Performance). This will make Blender use more threads which will speed up the render.
- **Turn the samples down**. It's fairly easy to remove a few fireflies later on in compositing, and will speed up your render time a lot.

Comment: I'll try it, I know it's experimental but I see people running those GPUs fine, I'll try the stuff, but in graphicsall does OSL stand for openCL or what?

Comment: No, OSL stands for Open Shading Language. I did a quick search and I think this one should work (it says it supports OpenCL): http://graphicall.org/110 let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Doesn't work, I've tried your suggestions but it's all still taking hours for a simple object with simple lighting, I'm trying to run Ubuntu now as I think it might be the problem with Win 8