# Blender 2.71 Cycles render preview graphic purple (no missing textures)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Some weeks ago I downloaded Blender 2.71 (Win64) from the official website. The version I was using before was the 2.69, which didn´t give me any problem. But the newest version wont let me use the render preview in cycles, showing me a purple screen instead. Firstly I thought the problem was on the version, but today I installed the program in some friend´s computer and works fine.

I have windows 7 (the same OS as my friends), Acer Aspire, and just formatted it. The blender render lets me use the render view though and I can render images (both with f12 and on the render options) in cycles. I have tried both win32 and win 64, as well as the portable and the installable versions. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: The scene of the image is the default one, with only the cube, the camera and the point lamp on display. The sky has no texture, just the default solid grey. The problem is that the whole viewport turns purple, which could mean that **it´s not a missing textures issue.** I think that the problem might lay on the graphic drivers, but I don´t know what to do. I really hope the next blender version or ATI actualization may fix the problem.

[image: Purple screen appearing as I click the render preview]

Comment: Would agree... It usally appears when textures are missing. Activate **Amaranth toolset** addon(in Testing category) to find out easyli wich is missing(scene debug panel)

Comment: Did the render was succesful? is only preview effected? (by the way between key and button is no difference)

Comment: But if the problem were the missing textures the objects should be the only ones affected, instead of having the entire viewport purple, shouldn´t them? This is the default scene, with only the cube on the 3D space. I have activated the Amaranth Addon, but I´m not sure what to do with it. The render in Cycles is successful, the only problem is the preview. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Are you using a Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: @AntonioGonzalezViegas If you have a missing sky texture, then the sky could be pink too.

Comment: I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series. and an Intel Core 2 Duo processor. I have not set any sky texture either, it´s the untouched default scene. I´m starting to think that the problem might lay on the graphic drivers. I am going to try reinstalling them, installing other versions and turning down the graphic hardware acceleration. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Cylces works in Nvidia GPUs with CUDA cores. ATI cards are know to have problems with the drivers. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/ati-radeon-hd-7770-no-gpu-rendering and this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15689/cycles-does-not-render-with-gpu and also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles/7486#7486

Comment: @cegaton cycles also works on cpu, so that shouldn't be the problem. Usually there is no gpu option for ati cards.

Comment: In the end I am working using f12 with low framing to preview my works. I will ensure that in the future my next computer has got a compatible graphic card. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @AntonioGonzalezViegas, I had the same problem with an ATI HD 2600 pro and it was solved by installing the latest drivers from AMD.